# Adjust predicted probability after smote

Tags: probability, calibration, imbalanced-data, smote

I have an imbalance data set and I used smote to oversample the minority class and undersample the majority class.
now, I want to check the test AUC using predict_proba of the model.

I have two questions:
1. Do I have to correct the probability if I am comparing AUCs?
2. How can I correct it (a combination of undersampling and oversampling!)

Answer (score 0):

(1) The good news is no, you don't have to correct when comparing AUC. The resampling correction is a strictly increasing function of the uncorrected score, so it doesn't change the order of cases, so the ROC is exactly the same.

(2) There is a simple formula for correcting after under/over-sampling, I forget what it is, I'm pretty sure a web search will find it.

Further discussion is best suited to stats.stackexchange.com.